# Two digits after comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have disabled input field, where result goes ("Kiekis" * "Kaina" = "Suma"), but result in a lot of situations displayed with more than 2 digits (Like 3 * 2.93) even if I used JS toFixed(2) function.

```
    $('#quantity, #price').on('keyup change', function() {
        $('#total').val($('#quantity').val() * $('#price').val()).toFixed(2);
    });
```

Here is all my code in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w5qz5exe/

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Comment: Don’t ask two separate questions in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching events on the input fields before they are loaded on the DOM. So, attach event in parent:

Also `toFixed` should be inside `val`, as whatever value is passed in parameter of val function is set as value of that element. So you need to send formatted value in this funciton :

Example:

```
$('div.row').on('keyup change', '#quantity, #price ', function() {
     $('#total').val(($('#quantity').val() * $('#price').val()).toFixed(2));
 });
```

Updated Fiddle - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/w5qz5exe/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an event handler to 'keyup change' on page load, but the new elements that you are adding to the DOM where not on the page at page load.  You will need to add that handler to the new elements *after* they are created.

You could put the 'keyup change' handler in a function and then when you add the new elements, call that function.

Comment: Ah.. googled that, but can't find correct solution for that :/ Can you give simple example? Thx

Comment: @Sprunkas I've expanded my answer, see above.

Answer (score 0):

What this does: sets the value of $('#total') to blah and then to a .toFixed(2) to a jquery object (as .val() returns $('#total'))

```
$('#total').val(blah).toFixed(2)
```

What this does: sets the value of  $('#total') to blah with at most 2 decimals:

```
$('#total').val(blah.toFixed(2))
```

Second one is what you really want